# How to get an instance of services in Angular 5 outside the context of a component?

Tags: javascript, angular

We're using Angular, but with these differences:

- We only use binding, HTTP and Material Design
- We use it in ES5 (Angular 5 written in ES5)
- We use it in the context of a Software Production Line (SPL) thus we're not following its opinionated structure.

We have defined a global variable called `app` and we want to get an instance of some of Angular's default services somehow, and instead of injecting them into each component, we want to reuse that single instance throughout the entire application.

Please don't advice on testability or similar things. This design has created us tremendous business value and we're enjoying industrial approach financially.

Then we have defined a `globalServices` service, that acts only as a placeholder to fire Angular's injection mechanism, so that we can have those singleton instances of `ng.http.Http` for example.

```
var globalServices = (function () {
    function globalServices(http) {
        console.log('constructor of globalServices');
        app.http = http;
    }
    globalServices = __decorate([
        ng.core.Injectable(),
        __metadata("design:paramtypes", [])
    ], globalServices);
    globalServices.parameters = [ng.http.Http];
    return globalServices;
}());
```

And at last, we used this `globalServices` in our root module's `bootstrap` section.

```
var RootModule = (function () {
    function RootModule() {
    }
    RootModule = __decorate([
        ng.core.NgModule({
            declarations: [
                RootModuleClientLayout
            ],
            imports: [
                ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule
            ],
            providers: [globalServices],
            exports: [],
            bootstrap: [RootModuleClientLayout]
        })
    ], RootModule);
    return RootModule;
}());
```

Everything seems to be working fine, and we get no error. Yet there is no console log and `app.http` is undefined. By putting breakpoints, we realized that the constructor of `globalServices` is never called.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Oh my goodness. Why use angular 5 if you are stuck using ES5? Why not just continue with Angular 1.X? Seems like your team is in for a WORLD of hurt when trying to find help online should you require it. Who the hell thought that was a good idea?!

Comment: @Pytth, money decided that it's a good idea. We have so many reasons. You can follow [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21352) for example